# View selected options on multiselect after disable on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

When i disable my multiselect using jquery, the selected actions do not seem to be visible on the application when it's run on internet explorer, but is shown properly on mozilla firefox and chrome.  Is there a way around this? Please advise

**EDIT**
A possible [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmLvz/3/). Am not able to get it work here.

Am just trying to `disable` the multiselect and still be able to view the select options on IE

Comment: Can you provide the code you're currently using?

Comment: @SpAm currently using to disable multiselect?

Comment: Yes, and the code for the multiselect. If possible create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), that will make it easier for people to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the background colour should be easy enough and works for me on every browser I tested with (including IE8)

```
var runMe = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById('RQBRAND');
    select.disabled = "disabled";

    for(var i=0;i<select.options.length;i++)
    {
        if(select.options[i].selected)
        {
            select.options[i].style.backgroundColor = "silver";
            select.options[i].style.color = "white";
        }
    }


}
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpAm/cjutm/11/

The color = "white" is for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find this [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#enabledisable) helpful for what you are trying to do.

You will then be able to enable/disable it with:

```
var $widget = $("select").multiselect(), 
    state = true;

$("#toggle-disabled").click(function(){
   state = !state;
   $widget.multiselect(state ? 'disable' : 'enable');
});
```

As far as I tested, it also works well with older IE versions.